# Is it safe to co_await and resume a coroutine on a different thread without synchronization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, c++-coroutine

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await) has this example for co_await, which resumes the coroutine on a different thread.

But is it safe to do so without synchronization?

Specifically, resuming_on_new_thread() starts with one thread, then resumes after the co_await with another thread accessing the same coroutine "frame". Normally if you access the same data from two threads you need synchronization.

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
 
auto switch_to_new_thread(std::jthread& out)
{
    struct awaitable
    {
        std::jthread* p_out;
        bool await_ready() { return false; }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
        {
            std::jthread& out = *p_out;
            if (out.joinable())
                throw std::runtime_error("Output jthread parameter not empty");
            out = std::jthread([h] { h.resume(); });
            // Potential undefined behavior: accessing potentially destroyed *this
            // std::cout << "New thread ID: " << p_out->get_id() << '\n';
            std::cout << "New thread ID: " << out.get_id() << '\n'; // this is OK
        }
        void await_resume() {}
    };
    return awaitable{&out};
}
 
struct task
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        task get_return_object() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
    };
};
 
task resuming_on_new_thread(std::jthread& out)
{
    std::cout << "Coroutine started on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    co_await switch_to_new_thread(out);
    // awaiter destroyed here
    std::cout << "Coroutine resumed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}
 
int main()
{
    std::jthread out;
    resuming_on_new_thread(out);
}
```

**Consider if the function has data:**

```
task resuming_on_new_thread(std::jthread& out)
{
    int data = 0; // Store some data using thread A.
    std::cout << "Coroutine started on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    co_await switch_to_new_thread(out);
    // awaiter destroyed here
    std::cout << "Coroutine resumed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    std::cout << data << '\n'; // Access data with thread B. **Is this safe?**
}
```

Comment: Think about the question you ask. Say, how do you know that the coroutine finished working and you resume it on a different thread? If you know that, it means you have already performed the synchronization - implicitly via some other classes. The proper question would be, "How to ensure that different threads do not access the coroutine simultaneously causing a data race?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The constructor of `std::jthread` is the synchronisation.

Comment: Makes sense. The constructor of jthread is called in the line `out = std::jthread([h] { h.resume(); });` and that takes care of synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe. Remember that when a coroutine suspends, it returns control back to the caller. So only the thread that resumes the coroutine can continue the coroutine body execution. In your example, the coroutine starts in the main thread, then it suspends, then resumes on `out`.

A data race would occur only if you tried to resume the *same* coroutine from *2 different* threads, which is **undefined behaviour**, as mentioned in the notes of `std::coroutine_handle<Promise>::resume()` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/resume)

> The behavior is undefined if `*this` does not refer to suspended coroutine [...]. A concurrent resumption of the coroutine may result in a data race.